# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: "ERROR: unnamed prepared statement does not exist" with pgsql 9.3 and pgpool 3.5.3

Tags: postgresql

Getting Error org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unnamed prepared statement does not exist , We are using db 9.3 and pgpool 3.5.3 version.

Comment: take a look at this; http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/3126.page

Comment: If you provide your actions (perhaps some code) raising this error, you may get better help.